# Как поставить строки из разных блоков друг под другом?

Tags: html, css

Вот мой код:

```css
main {
  margin-left: 9%;
  margin-right: 9%;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.filters {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.filters-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.filters-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.filters-ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.select {
  /*убираем стрелочку*/
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /*убираем дефолтную обводку*/
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  /*курсор изменяется при наведении */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.select-wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  /*  рисуем треугольник*/
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10.4px 6px 0 6px;
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tovar {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.tovar-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  right: 11%;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.tovar-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tovar-ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="filters">
    <h4>Строка</h4>
    <div class="filters-wrap">
      <ul class="filters-ul">
        <li>Цена1</li>
        <li>Цена2</li>
        <li>
          <div class="select-wrapper">
            <select name="select-category" class="select">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tovar">
    <h4>строка2</h4>
    <div class="tovar-wrap">
      <ul class="tovar-ul">
        <li>100009800</li>
        <li>50078700</li>
        <li>60</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image: Как у меня сейчас]
[image: Надо, что бы числа из нижнего блока стояли своими центрами под центрами "цена1", "цена2", "1"]

как так сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов

1. Использовать `<table>`
2. Использовать [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
3. Можно и через flex, Если задать сверху и снизу одни и те же настройки ширниы.

Comment: Ну раз уж сделали список, предоставьте воспроизводимые примеры в этими самыми технологиями, чтобы можно было посмотреть как подобное сделать.